# My VS CODE terminal starting directory becomes mysteriously long

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal, parceljs

My vscode terminal directory turns into a very very long combination of alphabets as soon as I type something in it. Like "\xe1\x84\x82\xe1\x85\xb3...."

[image: this is how it looks when terminal is opened.]
above is how it looks when terminal is opened.
[image]
above is how it turns into as soon as I type something in it.
[image]
above is what I get when I click 'split terminal' icon.

I used parcel to to configure this react project. Below is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "vanilla-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel public/index.html",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "^28.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "parcel": "^2.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  },
  "browsersList": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do not use special characters outside strings. Not as OS usernames, not as directory names, not as filenames.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you Chris. So it is probably because the project folder name is in Korean..?

Comment: Yep, I bet it is.

Comment: Your issue seems very similar to [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83496). I'd suggest reporting the problem (with a minimal repro) there.